# Obtaining Coordinates from form and display on map

Tags: php, html, geolocation

I am trying to enter two coordinates into a form and when the user clicks submit I want it to run the "getSavedLocation()" method. I also want the the 'latlon' variable in  the method to get the two coordinates from the form instead of the 'position.coords.latitude', could someone please tell me how to solve these two problems. This is my code.

```
<form action="getSavedLocation()" method="get">
  Latitude: <input type="text" name="saved_lat"><br>
  Longitude: <input type="text" name="saved_lon"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<p>Click on the submit button to view the position on a map".</p>


<div id="mapholder"></div>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getSavedLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition,showError);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }

function showPosition(position)
  {
  var latlon=position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude;

  var img_url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
  +latlon+"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
  document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML="<img src='"+img_url+"'>";
  }
  </script>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reloading the page, you may use the run the onclick to get you the result.

```
Latitude: <input type="text" id="saved_lat"><br>
Longitude: <input type="text" id="saved_lon"><br>
<button type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="showPosition();">

<p>Click on the submit button to view the position on a map".</p>


<div id="mapholder"></div>
<script>

function showPosition()
{
    //var latlon=position.coords.latitude+","+position.coords.longitude;
    var lat = document.getElementById("saved_lat").value;
    var lon = document.getElementById("saved_lon").value;

    var img_url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="
     + lat + "," + lon +"&zoom=14&size=400x300&sensor=false";
    document.getElementById("mapholder").innerHTML="<img src='"+img_url+"'>";

 }

 </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: Doing this creates a form and it displays the map only for the first record when I click on it and I can't click on any of the other search results. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: My mistake. shall use the id instead on name of the html input. it should work now for multiple clicks.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use the form tag here? All my search results get displayed on the button for some reason :/

Comment: I'm using the javascript with onclick action to perform the changes on client browser. Unless you need to do form submission to reload the page, which is unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Is there anyway of adding a marker to this coordinates? and also show the users current location? Thanks . Sorry for all these quesitons

Comment: I will recommend you to use the Google Maps JavaScript API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). It will be easier to shape the map and place the markers.